# Adaptive cards not rendering on Bot Emulator

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I am unable to see the adaptive cards on bot framework emulator.

[image]

Bot-framework-emulator version I am using is latest 4.90.0

Comment: Can you share your adaptive card JSON?

Comment: @RajeshSitaraman 
Please find the JSON here : 
https://pastebin.com/3bipgnzk

Comment: @freakomonk - What do you expect that card to look like? Your text block has no text and your action has no title

Comment: @freakomonk - Are you still working on this? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @Kyle Delany Sorry I haven't had a chance to work on this. Will look into this today and let you know. Thanks Kyle

Comment: @freakomonk - Can you answer my question yet? I'm only asking what you expect to happen

Comment: @Kyle Delaney Hi. Expected output was a list of suggestive actions. Found the issue. The backend API call was failing but there was no error logging. Fixed it from my end. Thanks

Comment: @freakomonk - Would you like to post your solution as an answer?

Comment: Am getting the same Adaptive Card rendering issue on Webchat Direct Line Channel and latest MS Bot Emulator 4.12.0.  Did anyone find the solution for this?

Comment: any update here ?

Comment: @Gel I have added the solution I discovered as the comment. Please go through it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This was in fact occurring due to backend API call resulting in no text being sent to adaptive card.

Checking the API response helped in fixing this. As @Kyle Delaney suggested in the comments, checking for the `text` in the adaptove card JSON also will expedite the triage.